# Does my Adjectle game make sense?

Tags: word-order

I've made a grammar game at https://adjectle.com

It is based on adjective order in a sentence; there is a puzzle once a day, and everybody gets the same puzzle.

Spoiler alert (if you were planning on playing the game today, 5th February 2022): the correct answer (according to me) is "The sleek, old, black, Egyptian, furry, hunting cat".

Is this correct? Is the order of adjectives in a sentence strictly defined in English? Perhaps it is a bit late for me to ask now, after the game has been produced, but it would be great to get some feedback to help me make some more daily challenges or to adjust the scoring logic a bit if necessary. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to think about a little re-wording because this is borderline spam as it's currently written.

Comment: @KillingTime I suppose it does look a lot like spam, but I wasn't sure how to mention that it is a game, and that basically any other combination of those words will be marked as incorrect. Also, some combinations will be marked as less incorrect than others depending on how many of the adjectives are in the correct order.

Comment: "*Is this correct? Is the order of adjectives in a sentence strictly defined in English?*" You created a game about the order of adjectives in English without checking the rules of said grammar. And "**Perhaps it is a bit late for me to ask now, after the game has been produced**" Yes, it is a bit. It's a bit paradoxical saying a cat is sleek and furry at the same time. There are too many adjectives in that example, no native speaker would imagine uttering aloud that description.

Comment: @Mari-LouA thanks for the reply - how is "sleek fur" a paradox? My understanding is that sleek means smooth or glossy, especially with reference to skin, hair or fur.

Comment: sleek and furry seems fine; sleek and fluffy would be more of a contradiction, but furry just means having fur and could just be in opposition to a hairless cat. And Lexico has "sleek (of hair, fur, or skin) smooth and glossy." So fur can be sleek.

Comment: Yes, fur and hair can be sleek, but "furry" suggests a cat with a thick , heavy coat. personally, I would not describe a feline as being  "a sleek Egyptian furry hunting cat" Very weird assortment of adjectives IMO.

Comment: The last time I looked at 'the Royal order', it was only an approximate rule, and a companion rule-of-thumb was 'never use more than three consecutive adjectives'.

Comment: No, that's not right. Or rather, when you use commas, it doesn't really matter what order the adjectives are in. The goal with ordering adjectives is to omit commas, e.g. *black Egyptian hunting cat*.